# Problemas com Migration

Tags: asp.net-core, ddd, migrations

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando arquitetura DDD. Em minha camada de Infra, tenho os meus modelos de dados, todos baseados em *Code First*. Estou tentando utilizar o *MySql* como banco de dados. Já instalei tudo que foi necessário (*EF*, *MySqlConnector*) e outros mais que são necessários.

Acontece que quando tento aplicar o *Migration* obtenho o erro:

**Caso 1: Quando aplico o *Add-Migration***

```
PM> Add-Migration
cmdlet Add-Migration na posição de comando 1 do pipeline
Forneça valores para os seguintes parâmetros:
Name:
```

O que deve ser fornecido para esse "Name":

**Caso 2: Quando forneço o nome do banco de dados que consta na `ConnectionString`**

**OBS: Forneço tal valor, porque não sei o que deve ser passado conforme explicado acima.**

```
The specified framework version '2.0' could not be parsed
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      C:\Program Files\dotnet\
  - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
  - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
  - The following versions are installed:
      1.0.11 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      1.0.12 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      1.1.8 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      1.1.9 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      2.0.3 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      2.0.7 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      2.0.9 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      2.1.2 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      2.1.4 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Como resolver tal problema?

Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Ele está te pedindo o nome da sua migration. Cada migration tem um nome próprio, para você conseguir identificar e reverter as modifcações.  
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/

No caso ficaria assim PM> Add-Migration MinhaMigration

Comment: Ok. Grato pela atenção. O problema foi resolvido.

Answer (score 1):

No uso de migration tu terá de se habituar com alguns comandos:

```
Add-Migration <nome-da-migration>
```

Para voltar a uma versão específica:

```
update-database –target "<nome-da-migration>" -Script -Force
```

Atualizar a sua base com as alterações do domínio:

```
update-database -script
```

O parâmetro -Script: serve para te devolver o script a ser executado em banco, caso não coloque o parâmetro, será submetido automaticamente em banco.

O parâmetro -Force é necessário quando houver algum tipo de conflito ou modificação de estrutura que com script simples não seja possível de se modificar. Com o uso do -Force ele cria um script da quebra do possível relacionamento. Essa ação, caso você esteja usando um banco de produção, irá apagar os dados contidos no banco. Sempre bom ter cautela no uso do Migrations e aconselho a não usar em base de produção. Somente para desenvolvimento.

Existem outros parâmetros ainda como o -Verbose: Serve apenas para exibir um log do que o migrations está executando durante a execução do update-database.